# Karma spec classification

Tags: karma-runner, karma-jasmine

Right now when I run karma it takes all "*.spec.js" and run time. We have both unit and integration tests. And when I am running unit tests I don't want integration specs to run. What is the best way to tell karma what spec to load. Like any name pattern, etc. I need to know how to configure karma so that it runs specific type of specs.

Any suggestion with example/link is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you can identify your integration tests by filename (e.g. *.integration.spec.js) then I would have two separate `karma.conf.js` files. One for integration (with `./*/*.integration.spec.js` in the `files` list), and one for regular work (with the same pattern in `exclude`). Then just run the one you need - or have them both running in separate consoles.